# How to deal with async variables in angularJS ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-directive

I've got a condition in `ng-if="ctrl.zoo"` (in some directive where `ctrl.zoo = ctrl.foo && ctrl.bar`). The problem is that `bar` initializes by async function call and angularJS for some reason doesn't update my UI even though I included `bar` to my scope. I google that it's a bad idea to watch other variables to assign a new value for another (basically watch for changes of `bar`). It did work perfectly though if I inline `ctrl.zoo` (e.g.`ng-if="ctrl.foo && ctrl.bar`"`). Is there any simple fix about it?

Answer (score 4):

If you assign `zoo = foo && bar` in your controller, that is the value `zoo` is going to stay as regardless of whether or not the value of `bar` changes.

If you want `zoo` to update, you have a couple of options:

1. Update the value of `zoo` again to `foo && bar` after your async function call is finished.
2. Write a function in your directive controller called `getZoo()` which returns `foo && bar`. Use that function in your directive's template and when you update the value of `bar` on the directive's scope, the scope will run a digest loop, and that function will return the new value. The reason that inlining `ctrl.foo && ctrl.bar` in your template works is because you're doing essentially this.

Comment: Actually I tried the 1st way: and it doesn't work as well, now I'll try the second one. I had 1: this.zoo = false; 2: async(result) -> {this.foo = result; this.zoo = this.foo && this.bar; }

Comment: Were you using an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)? If so, it may have been failing because that would not be tied into Angular's digest loop. You would need to run `$rootScope.$digest()` or `$timeout()` or something similar to force a digest loop to run. It would be much cleaner to avoid this and use Angular's `$http` service to perform HTTP request instead, as this is tied into the digest loop and will therefore update your view with the new data.